# Draw a trajectory (lines) around a sphere (earth)

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

I would like to draw a trajectory around a sphere. Each point is made of Latitude and Longitude coordinates. So, I was going to place each point by doing a first rotation (long), followed by a second (latitude) and then a translation (z).

But I can't draw lines if I do any transformation between `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` ... It's forbidden ..

Do you have any idea about how to do that ? Do I have to calculate the coordinates of each point (x, y, z) from lat/lon/alt by myself instead of doing transformations ?
(I read that transformations are faster than doing the job by ourselves ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to upload a vertexshader that does the conversion for you, yes, you have to do that. Also, the glRotate etc. functions are actually deprecated since OpenGL 3.0.

And 'slow' is relative. I am fairly certain that doing the rotation using calls like glRotate() etc is slower than just calculating the position in 3d-space of each vertex.

On a related note, if it is a trajectory you almost certainly want to follow a great circle on the earth instead of drawing them as straight lines in 3d-space.

Comment: About OpenGL 3, I can't use it because the software i'm creating will run on old computers which support only 2.1 ...
So i have to do things like :
x = calc(long, lat, alt);
y = calc(long, lat, alt);
z = calc(long, lat, alt); for each point to be able to draw a GL_STRIP_LINE ? (I don't worry about performance because i'm not drawing lots of thing)

Answer (score 0):

Just sample points on the trajectory and draw those as a GL_LINE_STRIP.

Here's some pieces of important information: Don't use the OpenGL fixed function matrix stack (glRotate, glTranslate, glScale, etc.). It's cumbersome to work with and things get so much easier when using a real matrix math library. Also fixed function has been removed from modern OpenGL. Which brings me to the second piece of advice: Don't use immediate mode (glBegin … glEnd), it's a performance killer and has been removed from modern OpenGL as well.

Comment: I sample points by doing some maths by myself to get x, y, z for each one ? (x = r*sin(A)*cos(B)
y = r*sin(A)*sin(B)
z = r*cos(A))
 I can't use openGL 3, do you know a good math library for 2.1 ?

Comment: @Lloyd0: Yes I mean exactly that. Math libraries are independent from OpenGL. Some offer convenience interfaces to OpenGL, but those are not mandatory to use. Also you can use glLoadMatrix to load a matrix into one of the FFP matrices (modelview, projection, texture, color) instead of into a uniform. That can be done with GLM just fine.